# INSERT into DB table with PDO prepare and bindParam

Tags: php, pdo

In simple terms can someone explain what I am doing wrong here - I am simply trying to insert into a db with with prepare and bindParam, this is inserting 0 and Null into all the fields.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO db_fruit VALUES (id=? ,type=? ,colour=?)");
$sql->bindParam(1, $newId);
$sql->bindParam(2, $type);
$sql->bindParam(3, $colour);
$sql->execute()
```

btw: this method has been working for me for UPDATE etc, but not in this case for INSERT

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, try this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO db_fruit (id, type, colour) VALUES (? ,? ,?)");
$sql->bindParam(1, $newId);
$sql->bindParam(2, $name);
$sql->bindParam(3, $colour);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: The upper-commas are not needed.

Comment: there you go @Jonast92

Answer (score 23):

Expanding on A.O's answer, the following are also valid:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO db_fruit (id, type, colour) VALUES (? ,? ,?)");
$sql->execute(array($newId, $name, $color));
```

And:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO db_fruit (id, type, colour) VALUES (:id, :name, :color)");
$sql->execute(array('id' => $newId, 'name' => $name, 'color' => $color));
```

Might just be personal preference, but I find this syntax to be much cleaner.

Comment: I have been led to believe (could be wrong, very green) that bindParam is secure and replaces my_real_escape_string. Is your method as secure?

Comment: @gavin yes. PDO binds the parameters just the same as if you were to call `bindParam()` separately for each.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO db_fruit (`id`, `type`, `colour`) VALUES (:id, :name, :colour)");
$sql->bindParam(':id', $newId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: You don't have to put the array inside `execute` because you already have the values inside `bindParam`