# PHP error. Data is not inserted

Tags: php, web

I am following some video tutorials. but whenever i run the code it shows this error.
in database my database name is phplogin, my table name is users. my columns name are id,username,password and name.
erorr shown is this:

```
     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''".$_POST['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8
```

code is under.

```
include_once ("db/phplogin");
if(isset($_POST['submit']));
{
    $query = "insert into users(username,password,name) values ("'".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['name']."'")";
    if(mysql_query($query))
    {
        echo "data inserted";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "data not inserted";
    }
}


   ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action='regiser.php' method='POST'>
   Name:<input type ='text' name='Name' placeholder='Name'><br>
   Username:<input type ='text' name='Username' placeholder='Username'><br>
   Password:<input type ='password' name='Password' placeholder='Password'>            <br>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: First thing i see ist that your input names start with capitals.

Comment: Your  script is open for **vulnerable sql injection**

Comment: Mysql is deprecated instead use `mysqli or PDO`

Comment: I've already answered your question 3 Hours ago with correction of code. @waqas. But, no response. Still stuck in problem.

Comment: name attributes and POST arrays are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$query = "insert into users(username,password,name) values ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['name']."')";
```

But, this is dangerous. Add this line to clean your input before it's saved in database:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $input = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_POST);

    $query = "insert into users(username,password,name) values ('".$input['username']."','".$input['password']."','".$input['name']."')";

}
```

A better approach is using PDO with binding params. It's secure, it's ready for the future (you're using deprecated mysql_query()):

- [INSERT into DB table with PDO prepare and bindParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599808/insert-into-db-table-with-pdo-prepare-and-bindparam)
- [Deprecated MySql Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321620/deprecated-mysql-functions)

UPDATE: It's more easy for you to use lowercase form field names, because PHP is often case sensitive (depending on the underlying OS). See [How can I make my local server case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582845/how-can-i-make-my-local-server-case-sensitive)

Comment: you missed the name attributes and POST arrays' letter cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Code** (Mistakes are listed below)

```
<?
include_once ("db/phplogin.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']));
{
  $query = "insert into users(username,password,name) values ('".$_POST['Username']."','".$_POST['Password']."','".$_POST['Name']."')";
  if(mysql_query($query)) {
      echo "data inserted";
  } else {
      echo "data not inserted";
  }
}
?>
```

Since you stated this error in @William Madede's Answer.

> Warning: include_once(db/phplogin): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'db/phplogin' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp1\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined
>   index: username in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8

**Mistakes**

1. Change this `$_POST['username']` to `$_POST['Username']`
2. Change this `$_POST['password']` to `$_POST['Password']`
3. Change this `$_POST['name']` to `$_POST['Name']`
4. Remove unncessary double quotes in `$query`
5. change `db/phplogin` to `db/phplogin.php` or give appropriate path of `phplogin.php`

[ **NOTE**: Mysql Is Deprecated. Instead Use `mysqli` or `PDO`]

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the unnecessary double quotes...
Update

```
$query = "insert into users(username,password,name) values ("'".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['name']."'")";
```

To

```
$query = "insert into users(username,password,name) values ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['name']."')";
```

Comment: Warning: include_once(db/phplogin): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 5

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'db/phplogin' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp1\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8

Comment: Warning: include_once(db/phplogin): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 5

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'db/phplogin' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp1\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 8

Answer (score 0):

You can also use insert query as below :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']));
{
    $u = $_POST['Username'];
    $p = $_POST['Password'];
    $n = $_POST['Name'];
    $query = "insert into users(username,password,name) values ('$u','$p','$n')";
    if(mysql_query($query))
    {
        echo "data inserted";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "data not inserted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: include_once(db/phplogin): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\firstlogin\regiser.php on line 5

Comment: how to remove this warning sir.

Comment: user file extension in include_once(db/phplogin) to include_once(db/phplogin.php)

Comment: i have no file sauch name as db/phplogin.php

Comment: what is your phplogin file location and current code location??

Comment: check proper location of phplogin.php file with db folder if db folder is not in same directory and outside the current directory then use "../db/phplogin.php" 
current Path :  a/b/c/myaction.php
and db is : a/b/db/phplogin

Then you can include like include '../db/phplogin';